# Compact Nested Single Folders for Finder

Tags: finder

VSCode has a [Compact Folders](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_compact-folders-in-explorer) feature in its file explorer that renders nested single child folders as one line. If there's a folder whose only child is another folder, they appear as one element. This makes it quicker to navigate deep folder structures.

[image: Demo of VSCode's "Compact Folders"]

How can I replicate this experience in [a macOS file explorer](https://mac.eltima.com/best-finder-alternatives.html) such as Finder.app?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available in Finder.

To give feedback to Apple and propose new feature, use [this contact form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) on apple.com.